# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, face-recognition, javacpp

I compiled [face-recognition](https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition) and was successfully running on an LG Leon (armv7I). When I installed the app on a [MyPhone UNO](http://www.myphone.com.ph/products/uno) with similar CPU architecture (armv7I), the error below occurs:

```
06-03 22:09:41.538 30619-30619/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition, PID: 30619
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.<clinit>(opencv_calib3d.java:94)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.<clinit>(opencv_contrib.java:104)
    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.PersonRecognizer.<init>(PersonRecognizer.java:44)
    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:109)
    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$3.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:320)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1223)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1240)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431) 
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136) 
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453) 
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97) 
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453) 
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85) 
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453) 
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.<clinit>(opencv_calib3d.java:94) 
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453) 
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.<clinit>(opencv_contrib.java:104) 
    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.PersonRecognizer.<init>(PersonRecognizer.java:44) 
    at org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:109) 
    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$3.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:320) 
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1223) 
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1240) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

When I looked into `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib` (which is decompiled by Android Studio) the value for linkpath is `linkpath = {"../lib/"}`.

This may seem to be the issue regarding the error.

Is there a way I could compile javacv.jar and maybe tweak around here?

I may be wrong that this part causes the error, do you have any idea where else?

## Update: 2023/05/27

I was able to compile face recognition, but I used a different library with different version. Unfortunately, I was not able to check which one was that since I'm no longer part of the project and the company.

Comment: have you solved the problem.Im also getting the same exception

Comment: it's a long time ago already, I've had it working but I used a different project which successfully compiled.

Comment: @SteveDhagz can you please share that project link or any idea for it. I am looking for solutions.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel unfortunately, I couldn't provide you with the link since I am no longer part of this project and have already forgotten where I got it.

Comment: @SteveDhagz Okay

Comment: I m also getting same exception, Can any one get the solution for this